# iterating a list in repeated calls to stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In a MySQL database, how do I make repeated calls to a stored procedure by iterating through a list of strings?  Each string in the list is a parameter that needs to be passed into the procedure separately.  I wrote some pseudocode below that calls the procedure manually for each string, but how can I re-write it in MySQL-compliant SQL so that the procedure is called at each increment while iterating through the list of strings one at a time?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `some_procedure`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure`(_paramname varchar(10))
BEGIN
-- code for procedure omitted for clarity of question
END$$

SET @paramname = 'cat';
CALL `some_procedure`(@paramname)$$

SET @paramname = 'dog';
CALL `some_procedure`(@paramname)$$

SET @paramname = 'lizard';
CALL `some_procedure`(@paramname)$$

SET @paramname = 'chicken';
CALL `some_procedure`(@paramname)$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `some_procedure`$$
```

Comment: It's much better if you do it in at application end than in DB side.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you, but this is just for some digging I am doing in my database this week to better understand my data.  This code will not be part of a lasting application.  What is the simplest that this can be in working code?

Comment: If you want to do in MySQL then it's hell ... you will have to split by `,` and loop through each value and call your procedure. rather if you use a programming language to do ... that would be pretty simple (if you choose PHP for example) there are lots of example out there in web.

Comment: Also, try rollbacking your edit to earlier state cause the code in your post is totally wrong (it's mix of both MSSQL and MySQL syntax).

Comment: @Rahul Thank you, but this is just simple data exploration that does not warrant looking up all the JDBC stuff required to call it from Java.  I rewrote my post to show a way of calling the procedure manually each time.  The manual calls are easier than the Java approach, but it would be cleaner if there were a SQL way of iterating the list of strings instead of re-setting the string value and then calling the procedure each time manually.

Comment: Threre are but it's bit messy. Will take a look once I have some time. Will let you know.